# Cancel slow-loading external scripts

Tags: javascript, json

I am dynamically adding script tags to the DOM so I can download JSON data. Occasionally something goes wrong with a download, and the script fails to load properly.

How do I tell the browser to give up on a script that has taken too long to load? I think this is important because the browser limits the number of open requests at one time, and I don't want to waste it with dead connections.

I tried removing the script tag from the DOM, but that seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can control how the browser loads a script once you've inserted it into the DOM.

However, if you use an XMLHttpRequest to download the JSON data, you can call the [`abort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#abort()) method if the request takes too long.

Steve

Comment: I was hoping to avoid XMLHttpRequests if possible. The cross-domain security is a whole different problem.

Comment: If your server supports PHP, you can write a PHP script that gets the contents of a remote webpage (PHP isn't limited by cross-domain security), and then just make an XMLHttpRequest to your PHP script. It sounds complicated, but it works.